# Visual Studio Code didn't warning

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can someone show me how to configure *C/C++ intelli* to add a flag to show warning syntax like SublimeLinter-gcc, or any other extension that can do the same?

Answer (score 0):

All the warnings and errors are shown on the Problem Panel, you can install VS Code IntelliCode or Intellisense extension for detecting the errors and warnings before compilation.
Here you can find how to configure the [IntelliSense for cross-compiling](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/configure-intellisense-crosscompilation)

Comment: So how can I add flag to get warning? When I code `int n = 3; int a[n];` non-warning show up.